# Concatenate 2 variables

Tags: vb.net, concatenation

how can I make this code working?

```
Dim c As Integer = 0
For iCol = 0 To reader.FieldCount
    Dim col+c As String = reader.GetName(iCol))
    c = c + 1
Next
```

Thanks

Comment: Use an array with `Redim Preserve`

Comment: you can't use `col+c` as your `String variable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `List<String>` as well:

```
Dim lst as new List<String>();
For iCol = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1
    lst.Add(reader.GetName(iCol));
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim list as new List<String>(reader.FieldCount);
For iCol = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1
    list.Add(reader.GetName(iCol));
Next
```

This is an improvement on the selected answer as it initializes the list with a capacity matching the number of fields.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hi Thank you very much Neaox! I'll add it into my code

Answer (score -1):

So here is my code :

```
Dim growingArray() As String = Nothing
For iCol = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1
    ReDim Preserve growingArray(iCol)
    growingArray(iCol) = reader.GetName(iCol)
Next
```

Source : http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/VB/0160__Collections/UseReDimPreservetoaddelementstoanarray.htm

Thanks to SSS

Comment: If you know the number of fields you are going to have (`reader.FieldCount`) why not just create the array once with the that size? There is no need to resize (redim) the array.